# Decode hex string with percentage symbol (%HH)

Tags: javascript, url-encoding

I need to change string from this:

```
Fast-9%20|%20Speed%20(Something-Cool)
```

To this:

```
Fast-9 | Speed (Something-Cool)
```

How can I do it in NodeJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

> The decodeURIComponent() method decodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component previously created by [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or by a similar routine.

```js
var str = 'Fast-9%20|%20Speed%20(Something-Cool)';
alert(decodeURIComponent(str));
```

Comment: But if I want to encode it again, `|` symbol becomes `%7C`. How to avoid that?

Comment: @ArnasA. For that you need to use regular expressions to replace the string as per your requirement! `decodeURIComponent` and `encodeURIComponent` is more global approach though..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var str = 'Fast-9%20|%20Speed%20(Something-Cool)';
str = str.replace(/%20/g, " ");
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var decoded = decodeURIComponent("Fast-9%20|%20Speed%20(Something-Cool)");
```